# Search for a string in a text

Tags: python, algorithm, search, text

After answering a question here on SO about finding a city in a
user-supplied question, I started thinking about the *best* way to
search for a string in a text when you have a limited data-set as this one.

`in` and `find` matches against a substring, which is not wanted. Reqular
expressions using "word boundaries" works but are quite slow. The
"punctuation" approach seems to be a candidate, but there is a lot of
punctuation [characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) that can appear both in question as well as
some in the name of a city (i.e. a period in "St. Louis").

Regexps are probably the best general-purpose solution, but I'm
curious if this can be solved using some other technique.

**The task is to:**

Find a city in the US in a user supplied text in the English language
regardless of case.

My code heavily inspired by http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import re

def timing(f, n):
    print f.__name__,
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in r:
        f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f()
    t2 = time.clock()
    print round(t2-t1, 6)


def f0():
    '''broken since it finds sub-strings, e.g.
    city "Erie" is found in "series"'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if c in Q:
            pass

def f1():
    '''slow, but working'''
    for c in cities:
        re.search('\\b%s\\b' % c, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f2():
    '''broken, same problem as f0()'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if Q.find(c) > 0:
            pass

def f3():
    '''remove all punctuation, and then search for " str " '''
    Q = question.upper()
    punct = ['.', ',', '(', ')', '"', '\n', '  ', '   ', '    ']
    for p in punct:
        Q = Q.replace(p, ' ')

    for c in cities:
        c = ' ' + c.upper() + ' '
        for p in punct:
            c = c.replace(p, ' ')
        if c in Q:
            pass

with open('cities') as fd:
    cities = [line.strip() for line in fd]

with open('question') as fd:
    question = fd.readlines()[0]

testfuncs = f0, f1, f2, f3

for f in testfuncs:
    print f
    timing(f, 20)
```

On my old dodgy laptop, I get the following results

```
<function f0 at 0xb7730bc4>
f0 0.14
<function f1 at 0xb7730f7c>
f1 10.4
<function f2 at 0xb7730f44>
f2 0.15
<function f3 at 0xb7738684>
f3 0.61
```

If someone would like to have a go on my testdata, it can be found
[here](http://pastebin.com/VMAuVG9n)

Comment: Another useful test might be using a pre-compiled regex pattern.

Comment: You can compile one big regex to match any city name. It looks like `"(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities)`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, **Prebuild regex for all cities (ie. one regex for all cities)** seems to be winning at performance. I used the same test case and here is the result.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import re

def timing(f, n):
    print f.__name__,
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in r:
        f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f()
    t2 = time.clock()
    print round(t2-t1, 6)


def f0():
    '''broken since it finds sub-strings, e.g.
    city "Erie" is found in "series"'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if c in Q:
            pass

def f1():
    '''slow, but working'''
    for c in cities:
        re.search('\\b%s\\b' % c, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f11():
    '''Same as f1(). Compiled and searched at runtime.'''
    for c in cities:
        re.compile('\\b%s\\b' % c, re.IGNORECASE).search(question)

def f12():
    '''Building single regex for all cities, and searching using it.'''
    regex ="(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities)
    re.search(regex, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f13():
    '''Using prebuild single regex for all cities to search.'''
    re.search(all_cities_regex, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f14():
    '''Building and compiling single regex for all cities, and searching using it.'''    
    regex = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities), re.IGNORECASE)
    regex.search(question)

def f15():
    '''Searching using prebuild, precompiled regex.'''    
    precompiled_all.search(question)

def f2():
    '''broken, same problem as f0()'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if Q.find(c) > 0:
            pass

def f3():
    '''remove all punctuation, and then search for " str " '''
    Q = question.upper()
    punct = ['.', ',', '(', ')', '"', '\n', '  ', '   ', '    ']
    for p in punct:
        Q = Q.replace(p, ' ')

    for c in cities:
        c = ' ' + c.upper() + ' '
        for p in punct:
            c = c.replace(p, ' ')
        if c in Q:
            pass

with open('cities') as fd:
    cities = [line.strip() for line in fd]

with open('question') as fd:
    question = fd.readlines()[0]

all_cities_regex ="(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities)
precompiled_all = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities), re.IGNORECASE)

testfuncs = f0, f1, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, f2, f3

for f in testfuncs:
    print f
    timing(f, 20)
```

Note: I have added 5 more functions f11 to f15.

Here's the output (as seen in my lappy):

```
<function f0 at 0x259c938>
f0 0.06
<function f1 at 0x259c9b0>
f1 3.81
<function f11 at 0x259ca28>
f11 3.87
<function f12 at 0x259caa0>
f12 0.35
<function f13 at 0x259cb18>
f13 0.2
<function f14 at 0x259cb90>
f14 0.34
<function f15 at 0x259cc08>
f15 0.2
<function f2 at 0x259cc80>
f2 0.06
<function f3 at 0x259ccf8>
f3 0.18
```

**Prebuild (`f13`) regex for all cities (ie. one regex for all cities) is good at performance. Also notice that, precompiling such prebuild regex (`f15`) didn't add to the performance.**

*Based on the comments above by @trutheality and @Thomas.*

Comment: Your solution wouldn't work, because the regex you wrote has the same problem as the `f0()`

Answer (score 1):

An upgrowth of your "punctuation" approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import re

def timing(f, n):
    print f.__name__,
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in r:
        f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f(); f()
    t2 = time.clock()
    print round(t2-t1, 6)


def f0():
    '''broken since it finds sub-strings, e.g.
    city "Erie" is found in "series"'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if c in Q:
            pass

def f1():
    '''slow, but working'''
    for c in cities:
        re.search('\\b%s\\b' % c, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f2():
    '''broken, same problem as f0()'''
    Q = question.upper()
    for c in cities:
        c = c.upper()
        if Q.find(c) > 0:
            pass

def f3():
    '''remove all punctuation, and then search for " str " '''
    Q = question.upper()
    punct = ['.', ',', '(', ')', '"', '\n', '  ', '   ', '    ']
    for p in punct:
        Q = Q.replace(p, ' ')

    for c in cities:
        c = ' ' + c.upper() + ' '
        for p in punct:
            c = c.replace(p, ' ')
        if c in Q:
            pass

def f4():
    '''Single regex which is also broken'''
    regex ="(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(c) for c in cities)
    re.search(regex, question, re.IGNORECASE)

def f5():
    '''Upgrowth of 'punctiation' approach'''
    r = re.compile('\W')
    #Additional space is for the case 
    #when city is at the end of the line
    Q = r.sub(' ',''.join([question,' '])).upper()
    for c in cities:
        C = r.sub(' ',''.join([' ',c,' '])).upper()      
        if C in Q:
            pass

with open('cities') as fd:
    cities = [line.strip() for line in fd]

with open('question') as fd:
    question = fd.readlines()[0]

testfuncs = f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5

for f in testfuncs:
    print f
    timing(f, 20)
```

It is pretty fast:

```
<function f0 at 0x01F9B470>
f0 0.092498
<function f1 at 0x01F9B530>
f1 6.48321
<function f2 at 0x01F9B870>
f2 0.101243
<function f3 at 0x01F9B3F0>
f3 0.304404
<function f4 at 0x01F9B4F0>
f4 0.671799
<function f5 at 0x01F9B570>
f5 0.278714
```